# How to make a 'data' URI image understandable for Google?

Tags: images, schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool, data-uri

I use Schema.org markup for my website to make it more understandable for search engines. I generate an image (using PHP) for each post. That image isn't a stored image with a specific URL. So it won't start with a domain name and end with something like `.jpg` or `.png`. Because it is not stored on the server.

Actually, the generated image looks like this:

```html
<img alt='title-1' itemprop='image' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA ... EWlAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==' />
```

Those `...` in the middle of `src`'s value stands for "a long string".

The problem is, [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/) cannot understand it as an image. Any idea?

**Note:** We have storage limitation on the server and cannot store generated images. That's why we're trying to generate it every time using PHP.

Comment: Have you tried adding a charset and testing it that way? Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8499679/2297309

Comment: Why do you need Google to understand this image?  If it is a generated image it isn't likely high enough quality to be indexed in Google Image Search anyway.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Please search for "معنی سلام" on google (it means "what's the meaning of hello" in Persian). You will see [three images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvDmc.png) (which are indexed) the same as images I'm generating.

Comment: Text on a plain background is very low quality.  High quality images for image search are large photographs.  In addition to being very low quality, you say your images are duplicate of something else out there.   Don't even bother.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller They are not duplicate. They are identical pattern. That text is different for us and something else out there.

Answer (score 1):

According to **[the information of Webopedia](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/structured_data.html)**:

> Structured data refers to any data that **resides in a fixed field**
>   within a record or file.

**[Google's recommendations for structured image](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies#images)** data tell us the following:

> **Images**
>
> When specifying an image as a structured data property, make
>   sure that the image actually belongs to the instance of that type. For
>   example, if you define the image property of
>   schema.org/NewsArticle.image, the marked-up image must directly belong
>   to that news article. All image URLs must be **[crawlable and indexable](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636)**.
>   Otherwise, we will not be able to display them on the search results
>   page.

Therefore, if you have several dynamic images for an object on your website, then these images should be linked with this object in your sitemap, as recommended by Google:

```
<url>
<loc>http://example.com/sample.html</loc>
<image:image>
  <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc>
</image:image>
<image:image>
  <image:loc>http://example.com/photo.jpg</image:loc>
</image:image>
```

In addition, using dynamic images, you need to take into account the fact that these images have a high-level expenditure of scanning budget. 
Check the **[Google confirms AJAX (i.e. XHR) calls consume crawl budget](https://searchengineland.com/google-confirms-ajax-i-e-xhr-calls-consume-crawl-budget-315816)**:

> One more thing to look at if you need to optimize your crawl budget
>   for the most efficient Googlebot crawl of your pages. The
>   clarification. The update (in italics added here) reads, “Generally,
>   any URL that Googlebot crawls will count towards a site’s crawl
>   budget. Alternate URLs, like AMP or hreflang, as well as embedded
>   content, such as CSS and JavaScript, including AJAX (i.e. XHR) calls,
>   may have to be crawled and will consume a site’s crawl budget.
>   Similarly, long redirect chains may have a negative effect on
>   crawling.”